# Are different eye colors indicative of chimerism?

Tags: chimerism

If an animal or person has different colored eyes, does that mean they are a [chimera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(genetics))?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will find this wiki entry [1] informative.

While chimerism is one possible explanation, it is certainly not the only one.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterochromia_iridum

Comment: A possibly easier to understand explanation of eye color [here](http://sandwalk.blogspot.com/2007/02/genetics-of-eye-color.html). One thing to consider thats not mentioned in the wiki article in answer is [incomplete penetrance](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/inheritance/penetranceexpressivity)